# SSRS - Can I use the output of one result set to create a second filtered result set

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Scenario: 
I have a relatively chunky piece of TSQL code which I need to run to populate SSRS report parameters. To remove duplicates in the value field, I am having to run the code once to get a distinct set of values. Then, in order to get all the associated keys, I am having to run the code again with the value. This is really inefficient. I want to be able to run the query once, prompt the user to select the appropriate variable, then retrieve all the associated values without having to go back to the dataserver.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE #mydata(
ID INT,
EmployeeName VARCHAR(100),
Dept VARCHAR(100))

INSERT #mydata
VALUES(1,'Jones', 'HR'),
(2,'Smith', 'Finance'),
(3, 'Miller', 'Finance'),
(4, 'Macpherson','HR')
```

If I want to display a parameter list so someone can choose the department, then retrieve the associated IDs, I am currently doing this:

Query1A:

```
select distinct Dept from #mydata
```

- Populates parameter drop down, user choice is stored in @depts parameter

Query2A:

```
select ID from #mydata where Dept = @depts.
```

(I need the ID itself, because this forms the basis for other cascading logic within the report)

Whereas what I really want to be able to do is either (some of this is obviously pseudocode to try to present what I am trying to do, please don't correct the pseudo code!!)

Query1B:

```
select Dept, ID from #mydata
```

(stored in result set $1B)

Query2B:

```
select distinct Dept from $1B
```

(2B forms the basis for the parameter selection; the parameter chosen by user is stored in @depts)

Query3B:

```
select ID from $1B where Dept = @depts
```

OR alternatively

Query1C:

```
select Dept, ID, rank() over (partition by Dept order by ID) as ranked from #mydata
```

(stored in result set $1C)

Query2C:
Result set $1C is filtered by `ranked=1` which forms the basis for the parameter selection; the parameter chosen by user is stored in @depts.

Query3C:

```
select ID from $1B where Dept = @depts
```

This would seem like a fairly normal thing to want to do, yet I can't find anywhere that describes this need or suggests that it is something MS has catered for. Before I give up, I just wanted to check if some else has had this issue and solved it!

Comment: You can filter data at the tablix/matrix level, if that's what you mean. If you want to filter more, just add more filters. You don't create datasets from datasets in SSRS.

Comment: I want to filter the result set which defines the available parameter values, not the final tablix. The table will be the end result of a number of other activities I need to do once I have the "ID" field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for makes sense and I would agree that it is a relatively common requirement. There's no way to get both the distinct list and the full dataset from one query within the report itself. There are a couple ways to achieve this though.

The first approach would be to use a table in the database that stores the results. For example, if the query takes a long time because of the business logic or aggregations, it may make sense to have the results saved in a separate table on a regular basis using a scheduled stored procedure. Then when you run the report, you are just querying this prepared dataset. If the query is slow because of the sheer volume of data, this may not help much.

Another similar option is to use shared datasets in SSRS. This is a way for you to save your queries for use in multiple reports. One of the nice features is that the data can be cached on a schedule. In other words, that query will be run automatically on a regular interval. When you go to view the report, it's not hitting the database again, it simply retrieves the cached data.

Depending on the size of your dataset and how the parameters affect it, this may not actually make the report faster. There is always a trade off of balancing how much work can be done before the report is run and how much storage space would be needed to cache it. But based on your question, this is certainly an approach you should try to see if you can make it work for you.